# php71-imagick unable to load dynamic library (XAMPP / APACHE on MacOS)

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

i would like to install imagick for my XAMPP server and i have a problem, since two days i'm trying to fix it.

The errormessage on XAMPP-startup:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/opt/local/lib/php71/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/imagick.so'
>   - dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php71/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/imagick.so,
>   9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib\n 
>   Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib\n  Reason:
>   Incompatible library version: libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib requires
>   version 21.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version
>   15.0.0 in Unknown on line 0

In my understanding, the problem comes with libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib, which require freetype in version >= 21, but i've version 15 installed...?

yesterday i tried to install the newest version for xampp but didn't had success...

Comment: i've tried to replace the ' libfreetype.6.dylib' file with a newer one. it worked with a lib-file which has the version 19.0 (but i need >= 21.0). with newer versions (i found versions 21.0 and 23.0) my apache server (xampp) won't start. when i'm starting apache, there are no messages to error_log, not even one message. any ideas? i really need imagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if someone has the same or similar issues, my solution was to use a MAMP-server ([link](https://www.mamp.info/)). There you can choose your preferred PHP-Version. MAMP comes with a lot pre-installed (but mostly not activated) PHP-Extensions like imagick.

In my opinion, MAMP is a lot easier to configure than XAMPP.